# Fit implementation

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, least-squares

Hello I am trying to fit a psf to an image. The background should be aproximated by lower order polynomials. If I just  take a constant it works fine:

```
def fitter(image, trueImage,psf,intensity): 
   p0 = [intensity]            
   p0.append(np.amin(trueImage)*4**2) 
   meritFun = lambda p: np.ravel(image-(p[0]*psf+p[1]))
   p = least_squares(meritFun,p0,method='trf')
```

Now I have the issue of how to define the x and y's for my polynomials:

```
#Does not work!
def fitter(image, trueImage,psf,intensity): 
   p0 = [intensity]            
   p0.append(np.amin(trueImage)*4**2) 
   p0.append(1)
   p0.append(1) #some clever initial guess
   meritFun = lambda p: np.ravel(image-(p[0]*psf+p[1]+p[2]*x+p[3]*y))
   p = least_squares(meritFun,p0,method='trf')
```

x and y are obviuosly the indices *i*, *j* of my image array, but how do I tell that my fit routine?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `np.ogrid[:image.shape[0], :image.shape[1]]`?

Comment: np.ogrid feels good.... What I did: `meritFun = lambda p: np.ravel(image - (p[0]*psf + p[1]*np.ogrid[:image.shape[0]] + p[2]*np.ogrid[:image.shape[1]] + p[3]))`. Is this correctly implemented? The code compiles but now my fitter is not finding a solution (which may be a numerical difficulty but I want to rule out something is wrong with my function. Again The model that I want looks like: `image - (A*psf +  c1*x + c2*y + c0)`

Comment: I am now pretty sure that np.ogrid did the trick. Thank you very useful function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul Panzer mentioned in the comments, one way of solving this is by using np.ogrid:

```
def fitter(image, trueImage,psf,intensity): 
    x = np.ogrid[:image.shape[0]]
    y = np.ogrid[:image.shape[1]]
    p0 = [intensity]            
    p0.append(np.amin(trueImage)*4**2)
    p0.append(0)
    p0.append(0)
    meritFun = lambda p: np.ravel(image-(p[0]*psf+p[1]+p[2]*x+p[3]*y))
    p = least_squares(meritFun,p0,method='trf')
```